# Can a UIButton subclass override x, y, width, and height properties that are already set in storyboard for the button?

Tags: swift, storyboard, subclassing

I'm working through a project that uses storyboard for the view layout but the alignment is off on various devices in which I know has something to do with constraints as well probably.  I'm curious to know if I create a subclass and apply the subclass to the storyboard view in question, then is there a way the subclass could override the current settings in storyboard?

I applied this subclass to the UIButtons in question but the layout is still the same when I run the app.

```
class SettingsBackButton : UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "back"), for: .normal)
        self.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 20, width: 32, height: 32)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set them in `didMoveToSuperview()`?

Comment: If you have autolayout constraints on the button then setting the frame isn't going to affect anything.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan No, I just set the class in storyboard to the new subclass that was created in hopes it would override the settings in storyboard.   I think I'll need to create the entire view in question programmatically.  If I go this route, I shouldn't have to worry about constraints at all, right?

Comment: @CosmicArrows if you create it programmatically why storyboards ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan When I inherited the project and it was already created using storyboards.  Do you think if I take the time to re-create the view programmatically, will I still need to worry about constraints?

Comment: I vote for completing it with constraints , frame-layout was the old  way , it'll  be faster and exciting ( when layout is complex ) to create the app UI with auto-layout , you may take some time to learn it and you won't write a frame line after

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can but only if this line

```
 self.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 20, width: 32, height: 32)
```

is inside `layoutSubviews` where the frame is to overwrite it's VC's initialization settings that has finished when this method is called

Comment: I tried overriding layouSubviews both in the subclass itself and in the viewController however this approach didn't work.  Thank you for the suggestion either way

Comment: Inside the class **viewDidLayoutSubviews** , inside the button class **layoutSubviews**